# Clear Content of Excel Using Python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, xlwings

I would like to clear the content of the Excel file using Python and re-write it at the end with different values. I would like to do it while Excel remains open and don't want to close before re-writing it again.

```
import pandas as pd

Tab = pd.read_excel("abc.xls",sheet_name="Sheet1")
Col_A = Tab['Col A']
```

The Col_A in excel has the following values currently. I would like to clear those values except the heading 'Col A' and update them with new values.

| Old Values |
| --- |
| 100 |
| 200 |
| 300 |
| 400 |
| 500 |

| New Values |
| --- |
| 600 |
| 700 |
| 800 |
| 900 |
| 1000 |

I would like to keep excel open and save the file after updating new values in Col A.

Comment: If you want to write to an open Excel file, consider using `xlwings` or `win32com` instead of `openpyxl`.

Comment: Why clear the cell first? A cell with a value does not prevent a new value being written to it. And to clarify, Openpyxl does not open the file in Excel so there wont be any Excel to stay open. As BigBen states you need a module that does use Excel such as those he listed. Then you want to ensure that visible is set to True otherwise you wont see the workbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example using Xlwings;

The sheet contains the values 100 to 500 in cells A1 to A5 in 100 increments.
The workbook is opened in Excel with this pre-populated Sheet displayed.
Python then waits for a key stroke to continue.
When a key is pressed these cells are updated with the values 600 to 1000 down the column overwriting the existing values in real time. Then waits for key stroke again.
When a key is pressed the Excel file is saved and Excel exits.

```
import xlwings as xw


with xw.App(visible=True) as app:
    wb = xw.Book('foo.xlsx')
    ws = wb.sheets["Sheet1"]

    input("Press any key to update values")

    ws['A1'].value = [[600], [700], [800], [900], [1000]]

    input("Press any key to Save file and exit")

    wb.save('foo.xlsx')
```